# How to modify Vite + Svelte project in a way that the resulting JS module exports what I want

Tags: svelte, vite, single-spa

### Long Story Short

I need to know how I can tell Vite that, when building my Vite + Svelte application created with `npm create vite@latest` (Svelte + TypeScript), the resulting JavaScript bundled module also needs to export what I want instead of creating a pure side-effects module.

### Details

Ok, this is the thing:  I need to learn **single-spa** to convert some application.  My application is already MiFe'ed and in React, and since I think Svelte does a better job, I would like to take the opportunity to move to Svelte for the shell (root) project.

I am essaying my conversion like this:

1. Create a Vite + Svelte application (I don't want SvelteKit for this because I want **single-spa** to route things).
2. Create some mock of my application's homepage and set a place where other MiFe's will load.
3. Install `single-spa` in this, my new root project.
4. In `main.ts`, do `registerApplication()` for a trivial MiFe project, then `start()`.

I did this, no issues and it seems to be working.

What I cannot get to work is the trivial MiFe project.

To create this trivial project, I decided to also do a new Vite + Svelte project.  I did it like this:

1. Create the project using `npm create vite@latest` and selecting Svelte with TS.
2. `npm i single-spa-svelte`
3. Export the 3 main lifecycle functions as per [this document](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-svelte.html), which is the documentation of the package in step 2.

This is `main.ts`:

```js
import singleSpaSvelte from "single-spa-svelte";
import App from './App.svelte';
import './app.css';

const lc = singleSpaSvelte({
  component: App,
});

export bootstrap = lc.bootstrap;
export mount = lc.mount;
export unmount = lc.unmount;
```

I then do (for this trivial MiFe application/parcel), `npm run build` and `npm run preview`.  Now I have the server running.  I examine the created `dist` folder to obtain the `index.js`' exact name (it has a hash to avoid caching issues) and copy and paste this into my root application, where `registerApplication()` is called, like this:

```js
registerApplication(
    'spa01',
    () => import('http://localhost:4173/assets/index-b10091c0.js'),
    '/spa01',
    { domEl: document.getElementById('spa01') }
);
```

Then I run my root and voilá!  **It doesn't work**.  The module object being returned by the dynamic `import()` call is returning a module with zero exports.

I know this because I modified the function to log to the console the result of `await`ing the dynamic `import()` call.

My conclusion is that Vite is bundling all modules into this one module that doesn't export anything.

Comment: Why *not* use SvelteKit? It can be adapted to just about anything and its client-site router that kicks in after first load behaves like an SPA giving you the best of both worlds (initial SSR, then dynamic client-side updates).

Comment: Hi.  After testing, I was wrong:  single-spa doesn't have a router in itself.  It just listens to URL changes.  I ended up using SvelteKit to do SPA routing.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to put Vite into [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode), or configure it to preserve the exports (which happens by default in library mode).

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      name: 'MyLib',
      fileName: './src/main',
    },
  }
  // ...
});

// or

export default defineConfig({
  build:{
    rollupOptions: {
      preserveEntrySignatures: 'strict',
    }
  },
  // ...
});
```

Would recommend just using SvelteKit, though.